# How to configure SSH host keys in cloudformation template?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys, cloud-init

I'm trying to configure an EC2 with known SSH host keys on boot using cloud-init in a cloudformation template. But now I can't SSH into the server. It's tricky to debug :-)

Here's the userdata part of my EC2 fragment from my template:

```
    "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
      "#cloud-config", "\n",
      "ssh_keys:", "\n",
      "- rsa_private: |", "\n",
      "    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "\n",
      "    MIIEowCBAAKCAQF71D8K9C/+K0a2fO+S9s441kSI44lF5ml++ewD+Mp115x9", "\n",
      "    /XwwTlvqxCIpxdzpzq4xXEqH48StHyYIjAOPxoS1/QG0Ti6OqU893PpukLdmV", "\n",
      "    kLZKn2ph4fTT2aMl...", "\n",
      "    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "\n",
      "rsa_public: ssh-rsa AAAAB...", "\n",
```

I also have entries for (ec)dsa_public/private as per the docs.

Is there some weirdness with cloudinit where I have to also specify ssh_authorized_keys as well? I assume my keypair's public key isn't now being pushed onto my EC2 by Amazon...

Comment: Never put your private key in any configuration, it's called private for a reason -- this key is supposed to reside on a trusted machine (e.g. your laptop).

Answer (score 7):

The UserData from your question is basically a shell script that runs at first boot of your instance. See the [documentation on UserData](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts) for more details on that.

If you want to configure a set of **public** keys, you can use [AWS::CloudFormation::Init](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html) instead.

In the files section, declare the authorized_keys file:

```
"files" : {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  "/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys" : {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "Admins", "userx", "sshPublicKey"] }, "\n",                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "Admins", "usery", "sshPublicKey"] }, "\n"                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    ]] },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    "mode" : "000600",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    "owner" : "ec2-user",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    "group" : "ec2-user"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  }
  ...
```

The user data in this example comes from the [Mappings section](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html) of the cloudformation template:

```
"Admins" : {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  "userx" : { "sshPublicKey" : "ssh-rsa AAAABxxxxx...xxxxBSES/H userx" },
  "usery" : { "sshPublicKey" : "ssh-rsa AAAABxxxxx...xxxxKM+aSe usery" }
}
```

Please test it first by using a different filename instead of *authorized_keys*, as indeed you will be locked out of your instance when you make the slightest mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this because I didn't have the keys to our prod env in AWS to ssh into instances to debug why CFN deployment was failing. For various reasons, including that I was troubleshooting something that had gone wrong with cfn-init itself, I found it a better strategy to add the following line to the top of UserData and pass the parameter `tempSSHkey` to CFN:

```
Properties:
  LaunchTemplateData:
      UserData:
           Fn::Base64: !Sub |
               #!/bin/bash -ex
               sudo echo 'ssh-rsa ${tempSSHkey} temp-ssh-key' >> /home/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys
```